# "BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!" error in Teams when using Bot

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've created a Bot application in Visual Studio 2017, which I want to use in MS Teams. This application is part of a solution, which contains 2 components, the bot application itself and a windows application, which I have created that is used by the bot application to retrieve an authentication token from Microsoft (using similar code to what is on this website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-uwp-v2).

When debugging the bot after hosting it locally, I'am able to use the bot successfully in Teams. There is no error. However, now that I have registered the bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework in Azure, I'm now having issues as Teams returns back the message "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue." In Azure I have a Bots Channels Registration entity, which in its settings points to a messaging endpoint that is https://.azurewebsites.net/api/messages. I also have a Apps Service. Now I have transferred the application id that I received when registering the bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework and have put this into the bot application in Visual Studio in the web.config file along with the app password.

After testing this in the Bot Framework Emulator I get "POST 401 directline.postActivity" and in the "Inspector-JSON" I get "BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!". This is my first bot application so I'm lost as to what I have potentially missed out so does anyone have any idea what I could try?

---

So here's what I have in my RootDialog.cs file, which where the endpoint will hit when the bot is used.

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            string userInfo = "";
            AuthTokenDeploy tokenDeploy = new AuthTokenDeploy();
            userInfo = await tokenDeploy.MsGraphUserInfo();
            if(!userInfo.Equals(""))
            {
                // send webhook to end user system
                await SendToEndpoint(context, activity, activity.Text, 
                userInfo);
            }
}
```

AuthTokenDeploy is an instance of another class, which is where the function to obtain the access token along with the user information from Microsoft is held. So I created a string "userInfo", which then takes the value given by MsGraphUserInfo().

```
public async Task<string> MsGraphUserInfo()
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            string Text = null;

            try
            {
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(_scopes);
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(_graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
            }

            return Text;
        }
```

Calling MsGraphUserInfo() will open the "AuthToken.exe" as a popup Window and ask the user to log in with their credentials. You can see from the code above that it acquires the access token first, which is then passed into GetHttpContentWithToken(), which is where a HTTP GET request is run against "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" and a JSON string is returned with the user information in it.

```
public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Now I feel as if this method of using a Windows application to allow the user to log in might not be the best way forward, hence why I've been reading and following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad. I would like to know whether it is possible to use what is on this page to allow my bot to retrieve an access token?

Comment: You mention app.config.  Do you mean web.config?  MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword should both be in the web.config or Azure Application Settings.

Comment: Aha sorry, I've updated the text as it is the web.config file not app.config

Comment: `contains 2 components, the bot application itself and a windows application, which I have created that is used by the bot application to retrieve an authentication token from Microsoft` I'd like to know where you install/host that windows application?

Comment: Its hosted in Azure in a sub folder (bin) to where the Bot files are located. From what I can see there are 3 files here to do with that Windows application, which are the following, "AuthToken.exe", "AuthToken.exe.config" and "AuthToken.pdb".

Comment: Please try debugging locally, to see if you can get more information about the error: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/  (not with the emulator, but the MS Teams channel)

Comment: I've tried it again using ngrok and following the procedure in that link but it still seems to work fine when tested locally. I now have a suspicion that this might be related to where the "Authtoken.exe" file and its components sit in Azure. Locally they are sat within its own subdirectories bin folder, which is where the Bot project will pick up the exe from. However, when the solution is hosted in Azure everything seems to sit in one bin folder and so I'm assuming the Bot project might be looking in the wrong place for the "Authtoken.exe"

Comment: `I'm assuming the Bot project might be looking in the wrong place for the "Authtoken.exe"` Could you share the relevant code of communicating with that windows application and retrieving authentication token from your bot application?

Comment: I've updated my original question to include the code and also another potential way of going about this, which might be a better way going forward without the need of a Windows application to do this authentication bit.